# Xcode 10: Storyboard not showing Identity, Attribute... Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

After I update to Xcode 10, The storyboard is acting very weird. Sometimes it's not showing anything for Identity, Attribute, Size, and Connection Inspector and even I clean the project also restart my Xcode and it's still the same. Here is an Image example: 
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[Alex Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509173/1107226) did not work for me. Try clicking on the 'Show Assistant Editor' button [image: show assistant exitor] in the top right. That worked for me.

Comment: Didn't see the icon, used Menu - Editor - Assistant, that did the trick.

Answer (score 21):

Just select your storyboard tab, duplicate it (CMD+T) and close the first one. The new storyboard tab should work properly now.

Answer (score 7):

Open View -> Inspectors -> Select Show Attributes Inspector .

Answer (score 5):

Click on Version editor in the right uppermost corner.[image]

Now again click on Assistant editor[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to go to File -> Workspace Settings -> Go to derived data location -> delete your project inside it! then clean and build your project

Answer (score 2):

Only restating Xcode did work for me

Answer (score 0):

Hide Utilities window and showing Utilities window again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how but the storyboard was not in my project's hierarchy anymore. Readd it and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

Just had this issue in Xcode 12.5.

Closing and reopening the storyboard file cleared it up for me.